# Jmeter regular expression to retrieve data between 2 words from the Response data

Tags: jmeter

I am looking for Jemter Regular expression to retrieve the number between CustomerID and GenerationMethod..

expected: **1209109736**

```
CustomerID":1209109736,"GenerationMethod"
```

Tried this, not working.. `(?=CustomerID).*(?=","GenerationMethod)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

> CustomerID":([^,]+?),"GenerationMethod"

Answer (score 0):

Your data is utterly like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), if this is the case - the best way to work with it is using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as `$..CustomerID`

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor Demo]

---

If the response is not JSON be aware that there is a [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) which does exactly what you need - extracts the value between 2 boundaries, in your case - words

[image: JMeter Boundary Extractor]

---

If you're still looking for a regular expression it would be something like:

```
CustomerID":(\d+),"GenerationMethod"
```

[image: JMeter Regular Expresson]